# Does Baqend provide a locking mechanism?

Tags: baqend

Im basically new in Baqend. Currently, I'm building an application for queueing, but in order to avoid race conditions I need some kind locking mechanism in the system, is Baqend provide that?

Is there any example that i could follow?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about your use case? There is an API for transaction in baqend but not implemented in the JS SDK so far. Many usecase can be implemented without using real transactions.

Comment: Hi Florian, for example, in one restaurant they have only 10 person capacity, and the restaurant only serves each person based on their sequence order.
The application will show how many reservations quota left and if they book the reservation they will get their sequence number

Comment: just read about partial update in baqend documentation, i will try to simulate the request using partial update, hope it works

Comment: Is additional help needed here? Or does the partial updates work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Baqend has a built in version for each object. If you send an update to an object that has already been changed your update will be denied. In that case you can refresh your local object and try again. Is that what you are looking for?

https://www.baqend.com/guide/topics/crud/#update